# shinyapps.io Timing Out When Scraping Data

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have a shiny app that works fine locally, but times out after 60 seconds when I publish it to shinyapps.io. The code that I believe it is tripping up on is a function from the `nbastatR` package called `game_logs()` (which should probably take 10-15 seconds). When I check the log for the app, it appears as though that line of code is run, but doesn't progress at all before the app times out.

Because the `game_logs()` function is pulling data from stats.nba.com, I wanted to see if anyone else has experience any similar issues when publishing an app to shinyapps.io that scrapes data.

The following lines of code should work fine locally and provide an idea of what I'd expect the app to bring back.

```
devtools::install_github("abresler/nbastatR")
library(nbastatR)
game_logs(seasons = 2020)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and found that increasing the number of seconds allowed in Timeout times from your browser in Shinnapps.io's Settings>Advanced settings (Startup Timeout and maybe Read Timeout) has fixed it.

Comment: Tried maxing the timeout to 300 seconds, but still ended up timing out. Pretty weird since I would expect this to take 20 seconds, max.